# Missing subdocument while trying to fetch a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Issue:**
I am creating an accounts table with the schema as shown below. I have just one account document for a user in a mongo server that's running in my localhost. After defining the schema and adding a single account document, I wrote an endpoint to query and fetch that document (`Model.find(id: '12345')`) using the id key. The resulting JSON document has all the data except the subdocument named `accRef` as show in the Schema below. When I try the same find query using the Mongo Shell, I get the results perfectly. I've been trying to find what's causing this for almost an entire day now, without making much headway. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I started with an empty schema and added each field one by one, starting with the id attribute and fire the find query. Every single time, I get all the 75+ elements and subdocuments, but the moment I add the accRef subdoc to my schema, this piece of info disappears from the result.

Is there a limitation to the number of subdocuments that can be defined in mongoose's schema?

Also, I cannot seem to insert/save any new account object using the same schema as shown below. However, I can perform this insert/save operation using the very same JSON object, using a client like MongoChef.

Here's my JS module where I've defined my schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/accounts');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const accountsSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.ObjectId,
  id: String,
  uuid: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  contactNumber: Number,
  dob: Date,
  email: String,
  originalEmail: {type: String, index: true},
  password: String,
  socialMedia: {
    facebook: {
      id: String,
      email: String,
      token: String
    }
  },
  domainInfo: {
    country: String,
    currency: String,
    lang: String,
    domain: String
  },
  profile: {
    type: Number,
    id: Number,
    points: Number,
    accumulated: Number
  },
  perks: {
    id: Number,
    type: Number
  },
  address: {
    address: String,
    postalCode: String
  },
  paymentInfo: {
    cardNumber: String,
    isValidCard: Number,
    paypal: {
      email: String
    },
    bank: {
      bankName: String,
      bankNumber: String,
      accontId: Number,
      accountHolderName: String,
      bankBranchCode: String,
      paymentTypeId: Number
    },
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    dateModified: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  },
  metadata: {
    timezone: String,
    ipAddress: String,
    signupMeta: String,
    clientUserAgent: String,
    signupUrl: String
  },
  accRef: {
    type: String,
    code: String,
    url: String
  },
  key: String,
  parentId: String,
  type: String,
  utm: String,
  bounced: Number,
  status: Number,
  isPoints: Number,
  isAdmin: String,
  dateTutorialCompleted: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  dateModified: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  dateAccessed: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  dateVerified: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  datePurchased: Date,
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

const Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountsSchema);

export default Account;
```

The function in the service class that fires the mongo query:

```
import Account from '../../models/mongo';

const getAccountById = (accountId) => {
  return Account.find({id: accountId})
    .then(response => {
      if(response.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Account Not Found");
      }
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
};
```

**Mongoose Version** tried with: **4.7.7** and **4.7.8** (tried both)

**MongoDB Version** tried with: **3.2** and **3.4** (tried both)

**Node Version**: **7.4.0**

Comment: Have you tried [mongoose query population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Comment: @Creynders: Yes. I did come across this. But splitting my schema just for the sake of this did not make a lot of sense to me. In terms of the logical grouping of data, the above structure makes sense for my scenario. All the details are tightly associated to the account and shall be accessed every time the account would be accessed. So splitting them into different collections and joining them! I am not sure how much sense it makes. If I do it, I'll have to do so just for the sake of using mongoose. Pls let me know if you have any different perspective on this!